# Advanced MVC.NET Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am currently trying to route in the following way.

- **/** routes to Home controller, view action, "home" as id
- **/somePageId** routes to Home controller, view action, "somePageId" as id
- **/Videos** routes to Videos controller, index action
- **/Videos/someVideoName** routes to Videos controller, video action with id param as "someVideoName"
- /**News** routes to News controller, index action
- **/News/someNewsId** routes to news controller, view action, "someNewsId" as the id.

So far, i have the following code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "TheSportsOfficeWeb.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NewsIndex",
    url: "News",
    defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "Index" },
    namespaces: new[] { "TheSportsOfficeWeb.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NewsView",
    url: "News/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "_", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "TheSportsOfficeWeb.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PageShortCut",
    url: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "_", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "TheSportsOfficeWeb.Controllers" }
);
```

If i go to /Home/_/About, i can view the page, if i go to /About, i just get a 404.

Is this possible in mvc.net? If so, how would i go about this?

Comment: Side note: order of routes in your sample is backward - default route would match everything and more specific routes will never get tested. Make sure to fix sample to show reasonable (most specific- to-least specific) order of routes before any suggestions can be made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `UrlParameter.Optional` from the `PageShortCut` route. You'll also probably have to reorder the routes.

This works for me (as the final two routes):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PageShortCut",
    url: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "_" },
    namespaces: new[] { "TheSportsOfficeWeb.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "TheSportsOfficeWeb.Controllers" }
);
```

And my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    public string Index(string id) {
        return "Index " + id;
    }

    public string _(string id) {
        return id;
    }
}
```

When you tell the routing engine that `id` is not optional for a route, it won't use the route unless `id` is present. That means that the engine will fall to the `Default` route for URLs without any parameters.